# Программно добавить свой текст в комментарий к заказу WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, order

Каким методом можно автоматически подставлять текст, уже после формирования заказа в поле "Order notes"? Например, получать текст из поля "Имя".
Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

Для начала нужно понять событие, на которое вам нужно это сделать. Как я понял из вашего примера это после оформления заказа, то можно использовать хук `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed`. Чтобы получить имя, используйте метод `get_billing_name`. Для того, чтобы добавить запись используйте метод `add_order_note`. Остальные методы можете посмотреть в класее `WC_Order`.

Пример:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'my_woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 10, 3 );

function my_woocommerce_checkout_order_processed( $order_id, $posted_data, $order ) {
    $name = $order->get_billing_name();
    $order->add_order_note( $name . ' bla bla' );
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Код рабочий, но добавляет немного не туда :) Нужно добавлять именно в поле "Комментарий клиента к заказу". Где сам клиент при оформлении пишет свои "пожелания для службы доставки", например.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'after_checkout_create_order', 20, 2);
function after_checkout_create_order( $order_id, $data ) {

    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    //Устанавливаем текст, который будем добавлять. В моем случае это "Дата доставки"
    $text = __('Дата доставки', 'woocommerce') . ': '. $_POST['delivery_date'] . ' '. $_POST['delivery_time'];
    // Получаем комментарий клиента
    $note = $order->get_customer_note();
    // Совмещаем комментарий (если есть) с нашим текстом
    $note = empty( $note ) ? $text : $note . '<br/>' . $text ;
    // Сохраняем
    $order->set_customer_note( $note );
    $order->save();
}
```